# Clicking a download button without ID or unique name selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website where i want to download an excel file. https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html

I want to be able to click the download button in a menu. To open the "download menu" (or dropdown if you like) I am doing the following:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']"))).click()
```

After opening the menu i want to be able to click on "XLS Downloaden" (very specific this one since i want the excel file)

I have tried clicking on the button by finding the text in the div element by doing the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]")))).click()
```

This however results in an "object is not callable" error

I also tried the following, but this results in a timeout error:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-menu-item ']//*[name()='svg']//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]"))).click()
```

So, how would i go about clicking "XLS downloaden" ?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: the link is at the top of the question already (second line). but this is the link: https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error i found a way to do this myself:

```
 download = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']")))  
download.click()
WebDriverWait(download, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-menu']//*[contains(text(),'XLS downloaden')]"))).click()
```

if someone knows a better way, please let me know